# ASP.NET_SessionId not being refreshed after Session.RemoveAll()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session-state, iis-express

I'm trying to persist the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie value (for auditing purposes) and find that the same value is being used across sessions. For example, while in development, when I hit 'F5', I've started a new session, right? But I'm seeing the same value being displayed.

Another (more real world) example, I'm logged in; make and note of the cookie value; and then log out (fires the code below) but still see the same cookie value.

```
    public ActionResult LogOut()
    {
        FormsAuth.SignOut();
        Session.RemoveAll();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

thx

Comment: This is displaying browser Session ID. close browser and again start . Id will change

Comment: That worked. This this mean that 'Session.RemoveAll()' has no clientside effect - that I still need to find a client-side method to remove the original Session cookie? or am I just looking at this whole thing wrong?